# How to design a elegant IP check API to support both IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: javascript, api, design-patterns, extjs

In my project, there are a lot of requirements about IP check. Because we write many functions for network devices. In some case, we don't need loopback IP and broadcast IP, and in some other case, it's valid. Some features support IPv6, others not.

So I design some basic APIs:

```js
Ext.define('Common.util.IPUtils', {
  singleton: true,
  
  isIpv4 : function(ip){},
  isMulticast_v4 : function(ip){},
  isBroadcast_v4 : function(ip, mask){},
  isLoopback_v4 : function(ip){},
  isAny_v4 : function(ip){},
  isIpv6 : function(ip){},
  isMulticast_v6 : function(ip){},
  isBroadcast_v6 : function(ip){},
  isLoopback_v6 : function(ip){},
  isAny_v6 : function(ip){}

});
```

In this way, Developers have to call like this:

```js
(Common.Util.IPUtil.isIpv4(ip) 
          && !Common.Util.IPUtil.isLoopback_v4(ip) 
          && !Common.Util.IPUtil.isBroadcast_v4(ip, mask) 
          && !Common.Util.IPUtil.isMulticast_v4(ip)
          && !Common.Util.IPUtil.isAny_v4(ip))// etc
     ||
(Common.Util.IPUtil.isIpv6(ip) 
          && !Common.Util.IPUtil.isLoopback_v6(ip) 
          && !Common.Util.IPUtil.isBroadcast_v6(ip) 
          && !Common.Util.IPUtil.isMulticast_v6(ip)
          && !Common.Util.IPUtil.isAny_v6(ip))// etc
```

Is it possible to design a more elegant API for potential developers?

```js
Ext.define('Common.util.IPUtils', {
  singleton: true,
  
  SUPPORT_V6 : 1,
  MULTICASE : 0x0001,
  BROADCAST : 0x0002,
  LOOPBACK  : 0x0004,
  ANY       : 0x0008,//0.0.0.0
  
  checkIP : function(ip, mask, supportV6, excludeIPType){
    if(Common.util.IPUtils.isIPv4(ip)){
      if(excludeIPType&MULTICASE > 0 && Common.util.IPUtils.isMulticast_v4(ip)){
        return false;
      }
      else if(excludeIPType&BROADCAST > 0 && Common.util.IPUtils.isBroadcast_v4(ip, mask)){
        return false;
      }
      else if(excludeIPType&LOOPBACK > 0 && Common.util.IPUtils.isLoopback_v4(ip)){
        return false;
      }
      else if(excludeIPType&ANY > 0 && Common.util.IPUtils.isAny_v4(ip)){
        return false;
      }
    }
    if(supportV6 == Common.util.IPUtils.SUPPORT_V6 
  && Common.util.IPUtils.isIPv6(ip)){
      if(excludeIPType&MULTICASE > 0 && Common.util.IPUtils.isMulticast_v6(ip)){
        return false;
      }
      else if(excludeIPType&BROADCAST > 0 && Common.util.IPUtils.isBroadcast_v6(ip)){
        return false;
      }
      else if(excludeIPType&LOOPBACK > 0 && Common.util.IPUtils.isLoopback_v6(ip)){
        return false;
      }
      else if(excludeIPType&ANY > 0 && Common.util.IPUtils.isAny_v6(ip)){
        return false;
      }
    }
   return true;
  }
});
```

Now, Developers will call like this:

```js
Common.util.IPUtils.checkIP('10.180.0.1', 16, Common.util.IPUtils.SUPPORT_V6, Common.util.IPUtils.MULTICASE|Common.util.IPUtils.BROADCAST|Common.util.IPUtils.LOOPBACK|Common.util.IPUtils.ANY)
```

I use Extjs to do this, which is a JavaScript framework. Any more good ideas to improve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody give me more suggestion. Now let me post my resolution to answer my question.

We can search some basic IP validators on google, but that can't satisfy my needs. eg. [IP address utilities for node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip). Because we are a network vendor, we have a lot of requirements about IP check.

I implement this utility with ExtJS, but the core design can be implement with many other languages.

The following is the core snippet, which base on bitmap to assemble many atom validate functions.

```js
Ext.define('Common.utils.IPDomainUtil', {
 alternateClassName : 'IPUtil',
 singleton : true,
 
 lang : 'en',

 IPv4   : 0x0001,// If support IPv4
 IPv6   : 0x0002,// If support IPv6
 
 //=============== Specific type of IP ==== begin ================
 // Types supported to exclude from IP pool
 EXCL_NONE     : 0x0000,// Exclude none, means any address is valid
 EXCL_MULTICAST    : 0x0001,// Exclude multicast address ( Class D ) : 224.0.0.0-239.255.255.255
 EXCL_CLASSE    : 0x0002,// Exclude address in class E ( Class E ) : 240.0.0.0-255.255.255.254
 EXCL_GLOBAL_BROADCAST  : 0x0004,// Exclude global broadcast address : 255.255.255.255  
 EXCL_BROADCAST   : 0x0008,// Exclude broadcast address ( host-identification with all ones ): 10.180.255.255/16
 EXCL_LOOPBACK     : 0x0010,// Exclude loopback address : 127.0.0.0/8
 EXCL_ANY          : 0x0020,// Exclude any : 0.0.0.0
 EXCL_NETWORK      : 0x0040,// Exclude network address ( host-identification with all zeros ) : 10.180.0.0/16
 EXCL_NETMASK      : 0x0080,// Exclude network mask : 255.255.0.0
 EXCL_LINKLOCAL   : 0x0100,// Exclude IPv6 linklocal address
 EXCL_SITELOCAL    : 0x0200,// Exclude IPv6 sitelocal address
 EXCL_GLOBAL    : 0x0400,// Exclude IPv6 global address
 
 // Types supported to include which maybe consider as invalid by default.
 ALLOW_INT    : 0x0001,// Include IP as int format.
 BEGIN_0     : 0x0002,// Include IP begin with 0 : 0.0.0.1
 SUFFIX_MASK    : 0x0004,// Allow format : 10.180.0.1/16
 //=============== Specific type of IP ==== end ===================
 

 /**
  * Check IP whether is valid base on params.
  *  
  * @param ipField  IP field which will be input IP to validate
  * @param netmask   ItemId or Id of netmask component, or the instance of netmask, or left empty.
  * @param ipVersion  IPv4 or IPv6 or both.
  * @param excludeBitmap IP matched {excludeBitmap} conditions is invalid.
  * @param includeBitmap IP matched {includeBitmap} conditions is valid, no matter whether exist in excludeBitmap.
  * 
  * @example 1 : Set validator which get from IPUtil. Now you can set netmask itemId or ID.
  *  [{
  *   xtype : 'textfield',
  *   validator : IPUtil.getIPValidator("netmask", IPUtil.IPv4, IPUtil.EXCL_MULTI_E_BROAD_LOOP_ANY_MASK)
  *  }, {
  *   xtype : 'textfield', 
  *   itemid : 'netmask'
  *  }]
  * 
  * @example 2 : Set anonymous function as validator to call IPUtil.checkIp. Now you can set netmask instance.
  *  [{
  *   xtype : 'textfield',
  *   validator : function(){
  *    var netmask = me.down('mask');
  *    return IPUtil.checkIp(this, netmask, IPUtil.IPv4, IPUtil.EXCL_MULTI_E_BROAD_LOOP_ANY_MASK);
  *   }
  *  }]
  * 
  * @example 3 : If no netmask field, you can set IPUtil.NO_MASK or leave blank.
  *  IPUtil.getIPValidator(IPUtil.NO_MASK, IPUtil.IPv4, IPUtil.EXCL_MULTI_E_BROAD_LOOP_ANY_MASK)
  * */
 checkIp : function(ipField, netmask, ipVersion, excludeBitmap, includeBitmap){
  excludeBitmap = excludeBitmap || 0;
  includeBitmap = includeBitmap || 0;
  if(!IPUtil.validateParameter(ipField, netmask, ipVersion, excludeBitmap, includeBitmap)) return true;
  
  var ip, maskIpString, canCheckMask = false;
  ip = Ext.isString(ipField) ? ipField : ipField.getValue();
  
  // Check whether accept integer IP
  if((includeBitmap & IPUtil.ALLOW_INT) != 0){
   if(IPUtil.is32BitsDecimalInt(ip)) return true;
  }
  
  // Check whether accept suffix mask
  if((includeBitmap & IPUtil.SUFFIX_MASK) != 0){
   if(!IPUtil.isIpWithSuffixMask(ip)) return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_suffixmask_invalid');
  }
  
  // Match IPv4
  if((ipVersion & IPUtil.IPv4) != 0 && IPUtil.isIpv4(ip)){
   // Check whether accept IP format begin with 0, eg : 0.0.1.1
   if(IPUtil.isBeginWithZero(ip) && !IPUtil.isAny_v4(ip)){
    if((includeBitmap & IPUtil.BEGIN_0) != 0){
     return true;
    }else{
     return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_begin0_invalid');
    }
   }
   
   ip = IPUtil.ipStringToInt(ip);
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_MULTICAST) != 0 && IPUtil.isMulticast_v4 (ip)){return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_multicast_invalid');}
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_CLASSE) != 0 && IPUtil.isClassEAddress_v4(ip)) {return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_classe_invalid');}
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_GLOBAL_BROADCAST) != 0 && IPUtil.isGlobalBroadcast_v4(ip)) {return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_globalbroad_invalid');}
   if(canCheckMask){
    if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_BROADCAST) != 0 && IPUtil.isBroadcast_v4 (ip, maskIpString)){return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_broadcast_invalid');}
   }
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_LOOPBACK) != 0 && IPUtil.isLoopback_v4(ip)) {return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_loopback_invalid');}
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_ANY) != 0 && IPUtil.isAny_v4 (ip)){return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_any_invalid');}
   if(canCheckMask){
    if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_NETWORK) != 0 && IPUtil.isNetwork_v4(ip, maskIpString)){return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_network_invalid');}
   }
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_NETMASK) != 0 && IPUtil.isNetworkMask_v4(ip)){return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_netmask_invalid');}
   return true;
  }
  
  // Match IPv6
  if((ipVersion & IPUtil.IPv6) != 0 && IPUtil.isIpv6(ip)){
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_MULTICAST) != 0 && IPUtil.isMulticast_v6(ip))  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_multicast_invalid');
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_LOOPBACK) != 0  && IPUtil.isLoopback_v6(ip))  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_loopback_invalid');
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_ANY) != 0   && IPUtil.isAny_v6 (ip))   return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_any_invalid');
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_LINKLOCAL) != 0 && IPUtil.isLinklocal_v6(ip))  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_linklocal_invalid');
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_SITELOCAL) != 0 && IPUtil.isSitelocal_v6 (ip))  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_sitelocal_invalid');
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_GLOBAL) != 0  && IPUtil.isGlobal_v6 (ip))  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_global_invalid');
   return true;
  }
  
  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_invalid');
 }
});
```

The following is my whole solution.

```js
Ext.define('Common.utils.IPDomainUtil', {
 alternateClassName : 'IPUtil',
 singleton : true,
 
 lang : 'en',
 
 IPv4   : 0x0001,// If support IPv4
 IPv6   : 0x0002,// If support IPv6
 
 // Types supported to exclude from IP pool
 EXCL_NONE     : 0x0000,// Exclude none, means any address is valid
 EXCL_MULTICAST    : 0x0001,// Exclude multicast address ( Class D ) : 224.0.0.0-239.255.255.255
 EXCL_CLASSE    : 0x0002,// Exclude address in class E ( Class E ) : 240.0.0.0-255.255.255.254
 EXCL_GLOBAL_BROADCAST  : 0x0004,// Exclude global broadcast address : 255.255.255.255  
 EXCL_BROADCAST   : 0x0008,// Exclude broadcast address ( host-identification with all ones ): 10.180.255.255/16
 EXCL_LOOPBACK     : 0x0010,// Exclude loopback address : 127.0.0.0/8
 EXCL_ANY          : 0x0020,// Exclude any : 0.0.0.0
 EXCL_NETWORK      : 0x0040,// Exclude network address ( host-identification with all zeros ) : 10.180.0.0/16
 EXCL_NETMASK      : 0x0080,// Exclude network mask : 255.255.0.0
 EXCL_LINKLOCAL   : 0x0100,// Exclude IPv6 linklocal address
 EXCL_SITELOCAL    : 0x0200,// Exclude IPv6 sitelocal address
 EXCL_GLOBAL    : 0x0400,// Exclude IPv6 global address
 
 // Types supported to include which maybe consider as invalid by default.
 ALLOW_INT    : 0x0001,// Include IP as int format.
 BEGIN_0     : 0x0002,// Include IP begin with 0 : 0.0.0.1
 SUFFIX_MASK    : 0x0004,// Allow format : 10.180.0.1/16
 
 // The following is some IP type combination which may be used frequently. 
 EXCL_MULTI_E_BROAD_LOOP_ANY_MASK : 0, // You can add combination by youself, but make sure meaning of NAME match the real value
 EXCL_MULTI_E_BROAD_LOOP    : 0,
 EXCL_LINK_SITE_GLOBAL     : 0,
 
 //======= Testable network mask patterns ==== begin ===========
 MASK_NUM    : 0x0001,// 0-32, eg : 16
 MASK_IP_STRING   : 0x0002,// eg : 255.255.0.0
 MASK_IP_INT   : 0x0004,// eg : 4294901760
 MASK_WILD_STRING  : 0x0008,// eg : 255.0.255.255 TODO
 //======= Testable network mask patterns ==== end =============
 
 constructor : function(){
  this.EXCL_MULTI_E_BROAD_LOOP_ANY_MASK = this.EXCL_MULTICAST | this.EXCL_CLASSE 
     | this.EXCL_GLOBAL_BROADCAST | this.EXCL_BROADCAST 
     | this.EXCL_LOOPBACK | this.EXCL_ANY
     | this.EXCL_NETMASK;
  
  this.EXCL_MULTI_E_BROAD_LOOP = this.EXCL_MULTICAST | this.EXCL_CLASSE 
     | this.EXCL_GLOBAL_BROADCAST | this.EXCL_BROADCAST 
     | this.EXCL_LOOPBACK;
  
  this.EXCL_LINK_SITE_GLOBAL = this.EXCL_LINKLOCAL | this.EXCL_SITELOCAL | this.EXCL_GLOBAL;
 },
 
 /**
  * Check IP whether is valid base on params.
  *  
  * @param ipField  IP field which will be input IP to validate
  * @param netmask   ItemId or Id of netmask component, or the instance of netmask, or left empty.
  * @param ipVersion  IPv4 or IPv6 or both.
  * @param excludeBitmap IP matched {excludeBitmap} conditions is invalid.
  * @param includeBitmap IP matched {includeBitmap} conditions is valid, no matter whether exist in excludeBitmap.
  * 
  * @example 1 : Set validator which get from IPUtil. Now you can set netmask itemId or ID.
  *  [{
  *   xtype : 'textfield',
  *   validator : IPUtil.getIPValidator("netmask", IPUtil.IPv4, IPUtil.EXCL_MULTI_E_BROAD_LOOP_ANY_MASK)
  *  }, {
  *   xtype : 'textfield', 
  *   itemid : 'netmask'
  *  }]
  * 
  * @example 2 : Set anonymous function as validator to call IPUtil.checkIp. Now you can set netmask instance.
  *  [{
  *   xtype : 'textfield',
  *   validator : function(){
  *    var netmask = me.down('mask');
  *    return IPUtil.checkIp(this, netmask, IPUtil.IPv4, IPUtil.EXCL_MULTI_E_BROAD_LOOP_ANY_MASK);
  *   }
  *  }]
  * 
  * @example 3 : If no netmask field, you can set IPUtil.NO_MASK or leave blank.
  *  IPUtil.getIPValidator(IPUtil.NO_MASK, IPUtil.IPv4, IPUtil.EXCL_MULTI_E_BROAD_LOOP_ANY_MASK)
  * */
 checkIp : function(ipField, netmask, ipVersion, excludeBitmap, includeBitmap){
  excludeBitmap = excludeBitmap || 0;
  includeBitmap = includeBitmap || 0;
  if(!IPUtil.validateParameter(ipField, netmask, ipVersion, excludeBitmap, includeBitmap)) return true;
  
  var ip, maskIpString, canCheckMask = false;
  ip = Ext.isString(ipField) ? ipField : ipField.getValue();
  if(netmask){
   netmask = IPUtil.getNetmaskComponent(ipField, netmask);
   if(netmask.getValue() && netmask.isValid()){
    canCheckMask = true;
    maskIpString = IPUtil.getMaskIpString(netmask.getValue());
   }
  }
  
  // Check whether accept integer IP
  if((includeBitmap & IPUtil.ALLOW_INT) != 0){
   if(IPUtil.is32BitsDecimalInt(ip)) return true;
  }
  
  // Check whether accept suffix mask
  if((includeBitmap & IPUtil.SUFFIX_MASK) != 0){
   if(!IPUtil.isIpWithSuffixMask(ip)) return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_suffixmask_invalid');
  }
  
  // Match IPv4
  if((ipVersion & IPUtil.IPv4) != 0 && IPUtil.isIpv4(ip)){
   // Check whether accept IP format begin with 0, eg : 0.0.1.1
   if(IPUtil.isBeginWithZero(ip) && !IPUtil.isAny_v4(ip)){
    if((includeBitmap & IPUtil.BEGIN_0) != 0){
     return true;
    }else{
     return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_begin0_invalid');
    }
   }
   
   ip = IPUtil.ipStringToInt(ip);
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_MULTICAST) != 0 && IPUtil.isMulticast_v4 (ip)){return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_multicast_invalid');}
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_CLASSE) != 0 && IPUtil.isClassEAddress_v4(ip)) {return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_classe_invalid');}
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_GLOBAL_BROADCAST) != 0 && IPUtil.isGlobalBroadcast_v4(ip)) {return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_globalbroad_invalid');}
   if(canCheckMask){
    if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_BROADCAST) != 0 && IPUtil.isBroadcast_v4 (ip, maskIpString)){return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_broadcast_invalid');}
   }
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_LOOPBACK) != 0 && IPUtil.isLoopback_v4(ip)) {return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_loopback_invalid');}
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_ANY) != 0 && IPUtil.isAny_v4 (ip)){return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_any_invalid');}
   if(canCheckMask){
    if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_NETWORK) != 0 && IPUtil.isNetwork_v4(ip, maskIpString)){return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_network_invalid');}
   }
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_NETMASK) != 0 && IPUtil.isNetworkMask_v4(ip)){return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v4_netmask_invalid');}
   return true;
  }
  
  // Match IPv6
  if((ipVersion & IPUtil.IPv6) != 0 && IPUtil.isIpv6(ip)){
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_MULTICAST) != 0 && IPUtil.isMulticast_v6(ip))  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_multicast_invalid');
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_LOOPBACK) != 0  && IPUtil.isLoopback_v6(ip))  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_loopback_invalid');
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_ANY) != 0   && IPUtil.isAny_v6 (ip))   return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_any_invalid');
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_LINKLOCAL) != 0 && IPUtil.isLinklocal_v6(ip))  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_linklocal_invalid');
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_SITELOCAL) != 0 && IPUtil.isSitelocal_v6 (ip))  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_sitelocal_invalid');
   if((excludeBitmap & IPUtil.EXCL_GLOBAL) != 0  && IPUtil.isGlobal_v6 (ip))  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_v6_global_invalid');
   return true;
  }
  
  return getLangStr('iputil_checkip_invalid');
 },
 
 getIPValidator : function(netmask, ipVersion, excludeBitmap, includeBitmap){
  return function(v){
   return IPUtil.checkIp(this, netmask, ipVersion, excludeBitmap, includeBitmap);
  }
 },
 
 /**
  * Network mask always have three patterns :
  * 1. Mask num (MASK_NUM). eg : 16
  * 2. IP string (MASK_IP_STRING). eg : 255.255.0.0
  * 3. IP int (MASK_IP_INT). eg : 4294901760
  * 
  * @param maskField  Network mask field which will be input mask to validate
  * @param patterns  Combination of MASK_NUM \ MASK_IP_STRING \ MASK_IP_INT
  * 
  * @example {
  *   xtype : 'textfield',
  *   itemId : 'netmask',
  *   validator : function(){
  *    return IPUtil.checkNetmask(this, IPUtil.MASK_NUM|IPUtil.MASK_IP_STRING);
  *   }
  *  }
  * 
  * TODO : Support IPv6 ???
  * */
 checkNetmask : function(maskField, patterns){
  if(!maskField || !maskField.rendered){
   return true;
  }
  var mask = maskField.getValue();
  
  if((patterns & IPUtil.MASK_NUM) != 0 // Allow mask number
    && IPUtil.is32BitsDecimalInt(mask)
    && mask >= 0 && mask <= 32){
   return true;
  }
  if((patterns & IPUtil.MASK_IP_STRING) != 0 // Allow IP string
    && IPUtil.isIpv4(mask)
    && IPUtil.isNetworkMask_v4(IPUtil.ipStringToInt(mask))){
   return true;
  };
  if((patterns & IPUtil.MASK_IP_INT) != 0 // Allow IP integer
    && IPUtil.is32BitsDecimalInt(mask)){
   return true;
  };
  return getLangStr('iputil_checknetmask_invalid');
 },
 
 getNetmaskValidator : function(patterns){
  return function(v){
   return IPUtil.checkNetmask(this, patterns);
  }
 },
 
 ipIntToString : function(ipInt) {
     return ( (ipInt>>>24) +'.' + (ipInt>>16 & 255) +'.' + (ipInt>>8 & 255) +'.' + (ipInt & 255) );
 },

 ipStringToInt : function(ipString) {
  return ipString.split('.').reduce(function(ipInt, octet) { return (ipInt<<8) + parseInt(octet, 10)}, 0)>>> 0;
 },
 
 maskNumberToIpString : function(maskNum){
  var mask = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   var n = Math.min(maskNum, 8);
   mask.push(256 - Math.pow(2, 8-n));
   maskNum -= n;
  }
  return mask.join('.');
 },
 
 maskIpStringToNumber : function(maskIpString){
  return (maskIpString.split('.')
     .map(function(i){ return Number(i); })
     .map(function(part){ return (part >>> 0).toString(2); })
     .join(''))
    .split('1').length - 1;
 },
 
 /**=============== PUBLIC : APIs of IPUtil ===== end ==================*/
 
 isIpv4 : function(ipString){
  if(result = ipString.match(/^(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})$/)){
   return Ext.Array.every(result.slice(1), IPUtil.validatePerBit);
  }
  return false;
 },
 
 isIpv6 : function(ip){
  if (ip.indexOf('::') < 0) {
   var match = ip.match(/^([a-f0-9]{1,4}:){7}[a-f0-9]{1,4}$/i);
   if(match){
    return true;
   }
  }else if(ip.match(/::/g).length == 1){
   var val = ip.replace(/::/, ':');
   var match = val.match(/^([a-f0-9]{1,4}:){1,5}[a-f0-9]{1,4}$/ig);
   if(match){
    return true;
   }else{
    match = ip.match(/^(([a-f0-9]{1,4}:){1,6}:|:(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){1,6}|::)$/gi);
    if(match){
     return true;
    }
   }
  }
  return false;
 },
 
 /**
  * 2130706434 (127.0.0.2) -->  pass
  * 2147483648 (128.0.0.0) --> not pass
  * */
 isLoopback_v4 : function(ipInt){
  return ipInt>>>24 == 127;
 },
 
 /**
  * ::1  --> pass
  * */
 isLoopback_v6 : function(ip){
  return IPUtil.ipv6ToSimple(ip) == '::1';
 },
 
 /**
  * 240.0.0.0-255.255.255.254
  * */
 isClassEAddress_v4 : function(ipInt){
  ip1 = ipInt>>>24; 
  return  ip1 >= 240 && ip1 <= 255 && ipInt != (~0>>>0); 
 },

 /**
  * ip/0-ip/32
  * */
 isNetworkMask_v4 : function(ipInt){
  var valid = true, MAX_32BITS = 1<<31>>>0, index = MAX_32BITS;
  while((ipInt & index)>>>0 != 0 && index > 0){// Find the first not 1 bit.
   index = index>>>1;
  }
  while(index > 0){// The other bits can't contain 0.
   if((ipInt & index)>>>0 != 0){
    valid = false;
    break;
   }
   index = index>>>1;
  }
  return valid;
 },
 
 /**
  * 255.255.255.255
  * */
 isGlobalBroadcast_v4 : function(ipInt){
  return  ipInt == (~0>>>0); 
 },
 
 /**
  * 3758096385 (224.0.0.1) -->  pass
  * 4030202113 (240.56.1.1) --> not pass
  * */
 isMulticast_v4 : function(ipInt){
  ipInt = ipInt>>>24; 
  return  ipInt >= 224 && ipInt <= 239;
 },
 
 /**
  * FF55::      -->  pass
  * 
  * FFhh::      -->  no pass
  * Fe55::      -->  no pass
  * FF5::       -->  no pass
  * */
 isMulticast_v6 : function(ip){
  return ip.subString(0,4).match(/^ff[a-f0-9]{2}$/gi);
 },
  
 /**
  * 3355443327 (200.0.0.127/30)        --> pass
  * 3355443327 (200.0.0.127/15)        --> not pass
  * */
 isBroadcast_v4 : function(ipInt, maskIpString){
  var maskNum = IPUtil.maskIpStringToNumber(maskIpString);
  var maskIpInt = IPUtil.ipStringToInt(maskIpString);
  return ipInt<<maskNum>>>maskNum == ~maskIpInt;
 },
 
 /**
  * 3355443327 (200.0.0.127/30)        --> pass
  * 3355443327 (200.0.0.127/15)        --> not pass
  * */
 isNetwork_v4 : function(ipInt, maskIpString){
  var maskIpInt = IPUtil.ipStringToInt(maskIpString);
  return ipInt & maskIpInt == 0;
 },
 
 isSiteLocal_v6 : function(ip){
  return ip.substring(0,4).match(/^fe[cdef][a-f0-9]$/gi);
 },
 
 /**
  * 0 (0.0.0.0)  --> pass
  * 
  * */
 isAny_v4 : function(ipInt){
  return ipInt == 0 || ipInt == "0.0.0.0";
 },
 
 isAny_v6 : function(ip){
  return IPUtil.ipv6ToSimple(ip) == '::';
 },
 
 /**
  * FE8A::         -->  pass
  * FE95:55::66    -->  pass
  * FEbF::         -->  pass
  *  
  * FEa::          -->  no pass
  * */
 isLinkLocal_v6 : function(ip){
  return ip.substring(0,4).match(/^fe[89ab][a-f0-9]$/gi);
 },
 
 /**
  * 200d::       -->pass
  * 3dfd:dd::a   -->pass
  * 
  * 3d:dd::aa    -->pass
  * */
 isGlobal_v6 : function(ip){
  return ip.substring(0,4).match(/^[23][a-f0-9]{3}$/gi);
 },
 
 isBeginWithZero : function(ipStr){
  return ipStr.substring(0, ipStr.indexOf('.')) == "0";
 },
 
 //===================================================================
 // Some basic private functions
 getLangStr : function(string){
  return IPUtil.i18nResource[IPUtil.lang][string];
 },
 
 validatePerBit : function(bit){
  if(bit >= 0 && bit <= 255){
   if(bit.indexOf("0x") == 0 || bit.indexOf("0X") == 0 // Hexadecimal
     || (bit.indexOf("0") == 0 && bit.length > 1)){// Octal
    return false;
   }
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 },
 
 is32BitsDecimalInt : function(decimalStr){
  if(decimalStr >= 0 && decimalStr <= (1<<31>>>0)){
   if(decimalStr.indexOf("0x") == 0 || decimalStr.indexOf("0X") == 0 // Hexadecimal
     || (decimalStr.indexOf("0") == 0 && decimalStr.length > 1)){// Octal
    return false;
   }
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 },
 
 /**
  * In case suffix mask, check whether mask is valid  
  * */
 isIpWithSuffixMask : function(ipString){
  var arr;
  if(arr = ipString.split("/").length == 2){
   if(!(IPUtil.is32BitsDecimalInt(arr[1]) && arr[1] >= 0 && arr[1] <= 32)){// xxx/0-xxx/32
    return false;
   }
  }
  return true;
 },
 
 validateParameter : function(ipField, netmask, ipVersion, excludeBitmap, includeBitmap){
  return true;
 },
 
 getNetmaskComponent : function(ipField, netmask){
  if(Ext.isString(netmask)){
   return (ipField.up('component').down('#'+netmask) || Ext.getCmp(netmask));
  }else if(netmask.isXType('textfield')){
   return netmask;
  }
  throw new Error("You set netmask parameter, but I can't get netmask component correctly.");
 },
 
 getMaskIpString : function(mask){
  var ipString;
  if(mask >= 0 && mask <= 32){
   ipString = IPUtil.maskNumberToIpString(mask);
  }else if(IPUtil.isIpv4(mask)){
   ipString = mask;
  }else{
   throw new Error(mask+" is invalid");
  }
  return ipString;
 },
 
    ipv6ToSimple : function(val, add, masklen) {
        var toSubmitTempStr = '';

        val = IPUtil.ipv6ToNomalLenth(val);
        val = IPUtil.ipv6ToLeaveContZero(val);
        if(add) {
            val = IPUtil.ipv6PrefixADDMaskLen(val, masklen);
        }
        if(val.indexOf('0:') == 0) {
            var returnStr = val.replace(/0(:0){1,7}:*/,'::');
        } else {
            var returnStr = val.replace(/:0(:0){1,7}:*/,'::');
        }
        return returnStr;
    },
 
    ipv6ToNomalLenth : function(val) {
        if (!(val.indexOf('::') < 0)) {
            var tempArr = val.split('::');
            var ipv6Arr = [];
            var tempBeforeArr =[];
            var countBefore = 0;
            var tempAfterArr = [];
            var countAfter = 0;
            if(tempArr[0] != '') {
                tempBeforeArr = tempArr[0].split(':');
                countBefore = tempBeforeArr.length;
            }
            if(tempArr[1] != '') {
                tempAfterArr = tempArr[1].split(':');
                countAfter = tempAfterArr.length;
            }
            if(countBefore == 0){
                for(i=0;i<8-countAfter;i++) {
                    ipv6Arr[i] = '0';
                }
                for(j=countAfter;j>0;j--) {
                    ipv6Arr[8-j] = tempAfterArr[j-1];
                }
            } else {
                for(i=0;i<countBefore;i++) {
                    ipv6Arr[i] = tempBeforeArr[i];
                }
                for(j=countBefore;j<8-countAfter;j++) {
                    ipv6Arr[j] = '0';
                }
                for(k=0;k<countAfter;k++) {
                    ipv6Arr[8-countAfter+k] = tempAfterArr[k];
                }
            }
            return ipv6Arr.join(':');
        } else {
            return val;
        }
    },

    ipv6ToLeaveContZero : function(val) {
        var ipv6Arr = val.split(':');
        for(i=0;i<ipv6Arr.length;i++){
            ipv6Arr[i] = parseInt(ipv6Arr[i], 16);
            ipv6Arr[i] = ipv6Arr[i].toString(16);
        }
        return ipv6Arr.join(':');
    },

    ipv6PrefixADDMaskLen : function(ipv6, masklen) {
        var ipv6Arr = ipv6.split(':');
        var maskbit = ['0x0000', '0x8000', '0xc000', '0xe000', '0xf000', '0xf800', '0xfc00', '0xfe00', '0xff00', '0xff80', '0xffc0', '0xffe0', '0xfff0', '0xfff8', '0xfffc', '0xfffe', '0xffff'];
        var index = parseInt(masklen/16);
        var offset = masklen%16;
        if(index!=8) {
            if(offset !=0 ){
                var prifixInt = parseInt(ipv6Arr[index], 16);
                var maskbitInt = parseInt(maskbit[offset], 16);
                var finalPrifixInt = prifixInt & maskbitInt;
                ipv6Arr[index] = finalPrifixInt.toString(16);
                if(index!=7) {
                    for(i=index+1;i<8;i++) {
                        ipv6Arr[i] = '0';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for(i=index;i<8;i++) {
                    ipv6Arr[i] = '0';
                }
            }
        }
        return ipv6Arr.join(':');
    },
 
 i18nResource : {
  en : {
   'iputil_checkip_suffixmask_invalid' : 'Not A.B.C.D/M format',
   'iputil_checkip_begin0_invalid' : 'IP begin with 0 is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_v4_multicast_invalid' : 'Multicast address is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_v6_multicast_invalid' : 'IPv6 multicast address is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_v4_classe_invalid' : 'Class E reserved address is not supported ：240.0.0.0-255.255.255.254',
   'iputil_checkip_v4_globalbroad_invalid' : 'Global broadcast address is not supported：255.255.255.255',
   'iputil_checkip_v4_broadcast_invalid' : 'Broadcast address is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_v4_loopback_invalid' : 'Loopback address is not supported ：127.0.0.1/8',
   'iputil_checkip_v6_loopback_invalid' : 'IPv6 loopback address is not supported ：::1',
   'iputil_checkip_v4_any_invalid' : '0.0.0.0 is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_v6_any_invalid' : ':: is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_v4_network_invalid' : 'Network address is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_v4_netmask_invalid' : 'Netmask address is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_v6_linklocal_invalid' : 'IPv6 linklocal address is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_v6_sitelocal_invalid' : 'IPv6 sitelocal address is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_v6_global_invalid' : 'IPv6 global address is not supported',
   'iputil_checkip_invalid' : 'Not a valid IP format',
   'iputil_checknetmask_invalid' : 'Not a valid netmask format',
   'iputil_checkdomain_invalid' : 'Not a valid domain format',
  }
 },
});
```